# Can Rails search across multiple columns in one query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I wrote a simple search function that just looks for the value in the "name" field. How can I rewrite it if I want to search more fields at the same time?

```
<%= form_tag search_tasks_path, :method=> 'get' do %>
        <p>
          <%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name] %>
          <%= submit_tag "Search" , :name=> nil %>
        </p>
<% end %>
```

Can Rails search find plural columns?

**UPDATE**
I made the following changes to the Controller and View, which caused the search field to become two and the search function to be disabled (only the full data is listed).

Controller

```
  def list
    @tasks = current_user.tasks.order(id: :desc)
  end

  def search
    if @tasks = current_user.tasks.where('name=? OR note=?', params[:name], params[:note])
      @tasks = current_user.tasks.order(id: :desc)
    elsif params[:name].present? && params[:saf].blank?
      @tasks = current_user.tasks.where('name=? and note=?', params[:name], params[:note])
    else
      @tasks = current_user.tasks.order(id: :desc)
    end
end
```

View

```
<div>
  <%= form_tag search_tasks_path, :method=> 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name] %>
    <%= text_field_tag :note, params[:note] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" , :name=> nil %>
  </p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand you want to search across multiple fields in your form.
You need to add another field to the form by which you want to search, and you must process the result of the response in the controller action.

```
@tasks = Task.where('name=? OR some_another_field=?', params[:name], params[:some_another_fields])
```

Comment: What should I do in the controller?

Comment: through the `@tasks` variable you can get the values in the view. You need to fill `@tasks` with the values you need. Your action in the controller might look like this, depending on what you need: 
`if params[:name].present? && params[:saf].present?
   @tasks = Task.where('name=? OR some_another_field=?', params[:name], params[:saf])
 elsif params[:name].present? && params[:saf].blank?
   @tasks = Task.where('name=? and some_another_field=?' params[:name], nil)
...
else 
  @tasks = Task.all
end`

Comment: I got a SyntaxError on the line ```@tasks = Task.where('name=? AND note=?' params[:name], nil)```

Comment: note=?', params...

Comment: I dont understand

Comment: Missed a comma after quotes

Comment: Should I replace the original```<%= text_field_tag :name, params[:name] %>``` with ```@tasks = Task.where('name=? OR some_another_field=?', params[:name], params[:some_another_fields])```? I tried it and it doesn't work.

Comment: pls read carefully and don't exactly rewrite what i suggested, i gave u the solution as an example of what ur controller could look like. u can write processing the way u need for ur tasks. Also in the first message I said that you need to add one more field to the form that u want to search by.  u need a note. `<%= text_field_tag :note, params[:note] %>` (new field in the form).  And `@tasks = Task.where('name=? OR note=?', params[:name], params[:note])`  is the code for controller action. The code in the comment is just an example of what ur action might look like under different scenarios.

Comment: I updated the question article. I made changes to the Controller and View, which caused the search field to become two, and the search function became ineffective (only the entire data was listed).

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question correctly. This seems to be the solution you are trying to achieve.
controller:

```
def list
    @tasks = current_user.tasks.order(id: :desc)
  end

  def search
    if params[:search].present?
      @tasks = current_user.tasks.where('name=? OR note=?', params[:search], params[:search]).order(id: :desc)
    else
      @tasks = current_user.tasks.order(id: :desc)
    end
end
```

View:

```
<div>
  <%= form_tag search_tasks_path, :method=> 'get' do %>
  <p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search" , :name=> nil %>
  </p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, this just gives two wrong results. First, no matter what string is entered, all the data will be found. Second, it will only find strings that exist in both the [:name] and [:note] fields.